# tensorflow.keras.fit uses more and more memory until crash

Tags: tensorflow, keras, memory-leaks

I am trying to solve an exercise from a machine learning book, where a classifier should be trained on the cifar10 dataset using tensorflow and keras. I have attached a code example. The code is running in a Jupyter notebook inside PyCharm.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

import time
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)

def build_model():
    # Build a model as instructed
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))
    for i in range(20):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,
                                     activation=keras.activations.elu,
                                     kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=keras.activations.softmax))

    return model

model = build_model()

# Load the CIFAR10 image dataset
cifar10 = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

X_train = cifar10[0][0] / 255.
X_test = cifar10[1][0] / 255.
y_train = cifar10[0][1]
y_test = cifar10[1][1]
print(X_train.max())
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Split the data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, shuffle= True)



model = build_model()
root_logdir = os.path.join(os.curdir, "my_logs_11-8")

def get_run_logdir():
    run_id = time.strftime("run_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    return os.path.join(root_logdir, run_id)

run_logdir = get_run_logdir()

tensorboard_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_logdir)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=5e-5), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_cb],
                    batch_size=32)
```

I am already running into problems here:

1. I do not get past a few epochs (10-20), because with each epoch, the python process takes up more and more memory. My machine has 16 GB, of which 12 GB are usually free. When memory is full, my IDE (PyCharm) crashes and the python process is killed. Is that due to a memory leak? What can I do to fix it?
2. For each epoch, keras measures an estimated time of how long that epoch took. However, the time measured is much smaller than walltime (24s/epoch vs. ~60s/epoch). The book I am following seems to reach much faster training on a much weaker machine. How can this be?

Comment: when i ran your code on colab it used 3 GB of memory and did not crash, so i assume there is no memory leak.

Comment: I can confirm, running this on colab works for me aswell. Any idea how my personal environment on my machine may raise this issue? I am running the same version of tensorflow (2.3.0) and tensorflow.keras (2.4.0) as colab does...

Comment: Addition: Running the code outside Jupyter Notebook works fine as well. This problem must be linked to Jupyter. Any idea?